# Why does my email confirmation display on Google Chrome but not Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, rubygems, internet-explorer-11

In my Ruby on Rails application I am using the letter opener gem to display the email message sent to the user to confirm that they have registered on the system. But the HTML does not work on IE but it does on Google Chrome, any ideas?

**There is no error message, it will display who the email is sent to and who it is from but there is no content, i.e. it does not display the content in welcome_email.html.erb**.

app/mailers/application_mailer.rb:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default sender: "ben@thorcinemas.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.first_name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.first_name %><%= @user.last_name %>.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.txt.erb:

```
Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.first_name %>
===============================================

You have successfully signed up to example.com,
your username is: <%= @user.first_name %><%= @user.last_name %>.

To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.

Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

app/controller/users_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # login is achieved by saving a user's 'id' in a session variable, 
      # accessible to all pages
       session[:user_id] = @user.id
       UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later
       redirect_to films_path
    else
       render action: "new"
    end
  end
```

Comment: When you say "it does not work in ie" you need to be more specific by providing an error if there is an error or how it "does not work". Screenshot may be useful.

Comment: Sorry, I have just updated the question

Comment: Your Ruby code looks fine. You should view the page source in IE, and see if you can find the content you expect in the source. It may be being hidden by some JS or CSS property.

Comment: On the page there is a link so that I can either choose "View HTML" or "View Text", the "View Text" works but what I really want is to display the HTML.